# Multiple live streams one webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video, live-streaming

Hello i'm trying to make a web application where myself and three friends could all stream video from our webcams onto an HTML page and then i'll make an overlay for stats, details, life totals ect ect. I feel like i can figure out the overlay part, but im not sure how to get multiple webcam inputs onto my page.

I've followed the tutorial here https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm to make the javascript tag  to get my own webcam to embed on the page but im not sure how to get other user's to embed. Also, i'm using Spring as my backend

Thanks for any help!

Here is the code I have

The Head

```
    <style>
      #container {
          margin: 0px auto;
          width: 500px;
          height: 375px;
          border: 10px #333 solid;
        }
        #videoElement {
          width: 500px;
          height: 375px;
          background-color: #666;
        }
    </style>
```

The Body

```
    <div id="container2">
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement2">

        </video>
    </div>
    <script>
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function (err0r) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not immediately clear from your description whether you're trying to get multiple cameras on one device to show up on the web page, or you're trying to embed streaming videos from multiple sources. Because what you're describing not common, I think you need to go into granular detail about what you're trying to achieve, with a summary at the top

Comment: If the number of video sources you put on the page is constant, e. g. 3, then the base thing you need to resolve is the identifiers `container` and `videoElement`. You may duplicate the code 3 times and globally change the identifiers of 1st section to `container1`, `videoElement1`, 2nd section: `container2`, `videoElement2`, 3rd section to: `container3`, `videoElement3`. What you shown here - there it wasn't done globally, but it's important. If you want to put random number of videos, it's a good time for learning JS arrays, DOM model and CSS classes...

Answer (score 0):

I am too working on some similar stuff.

Below is the html file with the inline javascript.
Just try to add some elements and change ID name and try to make the same again. I hope it will help you. If not we can discuss it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Camera API</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" 
  media="screen" /> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
    <button id="capture">Capture</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <p></p>
    <script>
      const player = document.getElementById("player");
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const captureButton = document.getElementById("capture");

      const constraints = {
        video: true
      };

      captureButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
        context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);

        let str = dataURI.slice(23);
        // alert(str);
        console.log(str);

        document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML=(str);
      });

      // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => 
      {
        player.srcObject = stream;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Camera API</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" 
    media="screen" /> -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
    <button id="capture">Capture</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <h1>HELLO1</h1>
    <p></p>
     <video id="player1" controls autoplay></video>
    <button id="capture1">Capture</button>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <h1>HELLO2</h1>
    <p></p>
     <video id="player2" controls autoplay></video>
    <button id="capture2">Capture</button>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="320" height="240"></canvas>
    <h1>HELLO3</h1>
    <p></p>
    
    <script>
      // For first window of the stream
      const player = document.getElementById("player");
      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const captureButton = document.getElementById("capture");

      const constraints = {
        video: true
      };

      captureButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
        context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const dataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);

        let str = dataURI.slice(23);
        // alert(str);
        console.log(str);
        
        document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML=(str);
      });

      // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => 
      {
        player.srcObject = stream;
      });
      
      const player1 = document.getElementById("player1");
      const canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
      const context1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const captureButton2 = document.getElementById("capture1");
      

      captureButton2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Draw the video frame to the canvas.
        context1.drawImage(player1, 2, 2, canvas.width, 
        canvas.height);
        const dataURI2 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
          
         alert(dataURI2);
        
      });

      // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => 
      {
        player1.srcObject = stream;
      });
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, Can multiple video and canvas elements cause latency? Is this the best method for you? I would love to hear if you have any other ideas. Thank you.

Comment: It was my university project and i think that latency will not be the issue. Also you can give it a try by making more divs